# How to match a date or specific work in regex in this pattern in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match-all

I'm trying to grab the Time that will work for the following divs source-code:

```
<div class="smallfont">
                (09-03-2015, 09:16 PM)
</div>

<div class="smallfont">
                (Yesterday, 11:11 AM)
</div>

<div class="smallfont">
                (Today, 12:10 PM)
</div>
```

There is a lot of surrounding code but as long as it begins with "smallfont"> followed by carriage-return line-feed and maybe spaces/tabs, to go along with begin (

I'm really close. I have it working if it's just the 1st scenario with the Date, but it doesn't work if it's Today or Yesterday:

```
preg_match_all('/smallfont">[\n\r\s\t]+\([0-9\-]+,(.*?)\)/s', $output, $matchesTime);
```

2nd thing: Is it also possible to write code that'll then loop through and replace the Yesterday and Today with the appropriate date?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you not use a DOM parser to do this?

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to use regexp for HTML parsing. Use something like simplehtmldom to find your elements, fetch the values, and then go from there. That will simplify the pattern a great deal. - You might even simply be able to use `strtotime` to parse the date, assuming the date is in some known format.

Comment: Thanks @RobbieAverill - I have it working pretty well now for these fields but other fields deep within many divs that have no classes are giving a hard time and I think DOM will help with that. I haven't used DOM parsers before so I am now looking into them. Thanks again!

Comment: Paul- look into Xpath, you can access elements no matter where they are in the DOM

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use most consistent parts `09:16 PM` `11:11 AM` `12:10 PM` as an end mark.

To match those `\d+:\d+\s+[AP]M` and combine with sourroundings [like this](https://regex101.com/r/vR7zJ9/2).

```
smallfont">\s*\(\s*((?:[^,]+,\s*)?\d+:\d+\s+[AP]M)
```

`\s` matches a whitespace and includes `\t` `\r` `\n` already. `\d` matches a digit.

For use with `preg_match_all`. First group contains the date string matches.

> 2nd thing: ...replace the Yesterday and Today with the appropriate date

```
echo date("d-m-Y, h:i A", strtotime("yesterday, 09:16 PM"));
```

Comment: Thanks! I definitely used strtotime to modify the dates doing that first helped.

Answer (score -1):

Just write all the possibilities in combination with `[0-9]+`

```
preg_match_all('/<div\b[^>]*\bclass="smallfont">[\n\r\s\t]+\((?:Today|Tomorrow|Yesterday|[0-9\-]+),\s*(.*?)\)/s', $output, $matchesTime);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eU8oO7/1)

Comment: Thanks @Avinash Raj. I didn't know about that DEMO link so that helped when I put the entire code in

Comment: [Accept an answer which you love the most.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)